# How to use jquery selector in xslt?

Tags: c#, jquery-selectors

I want to use a javascript function inside a xslt template that uses a jquery selector, but it returns the following error:
"Variable '$' has not been declared"

I'm using the following code:

```
function myFunction(buttonId)
{
    var button = $('input[id$="buttonId"]');
    //do something
}

]]>
```

Is that possible to do?
Thanks!

Comment: "Variable '$' has not been declared", this means. you need to include the Jquery scripts in the top of head element, so that you can access your jquery code

Answer (score 0):

```
"Variable '$' has not been declared",
```

will occur when you not included the jquery library in your application.

add this to your head element of the page, then try it out.

```
 <script src="yourJquerySourcePath" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

or else alternativiley you can use Jquery CDN. [Jquery CDN](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery)

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```